# Picking column names from an excel sheet in sql server while writing a macro

Tags: vba, sql-server-2008

I am writing a macro for automating some task where i need to pick column names from an excel sheet , use that columns in select statement in sql and then fetch the values for those columns from database table. is there any way through which i can acheive this.
e.g.
in my DB there is a table employee having column names as - empname,empadd,empcontact ,empsal,dep,branch,location and 50 more columns.

my excel sheet is having 3 column names empname,empadd,laction.

now i want my code to pick only those 3 columns which are in excel and fetch the values from employee database.

i.e. select empname,empadd, location from employee;

i tried multiple things but no luck.
it would be great if anyone can suggest some way. thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i tried to cocatinate these fields and make these a single cell value as a placeholder. after that i uses this placeholder in my vba code.  dim placeholder as string   set rs = con.execute(" select " & placehoder &" from emolyee"). here the placeholder is having that concatenated columns seperated with comma

Comment: I did it..and acheived my result from the same concept ... Thanks